# How can I make sure that my Google Analytics Self-Referral Issues is related to a cookie lost

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

It will be an open question since I'm not really sure about the issue I'm facing.

I'm working on a website where I see more or less 5% of sessions coming from Self-Referral. My default url is like this `fr.my-website.com/` and I have the following url in my Referral Exclusion List : `my-website.com/`

1- Do I need to add `fr.my-website.com/` in my Referral Exclusion List ?

2- I really would like to understand why do I have so much Self-Referral. I'm sure that is not about tracking code missing or 
incorrect cross-domain or subdomain tracking. I've also check to make sure that this Self-Referral doesn't happen on my funnel purchase. I feel like it's more about cookie lost between some pages. Is it possible ? how can I make sure of that ?

Comment: If you have users entering via your subdomain make sure that the cookie domain is set to "auto". Else the cookie will be set for the subdomain, and users who enter via the subdomain and then enter the main domain will receive a new cookie since per default the cookie is set for the current domain. The "auto" setting will always set the cookie to the highest possible level of your domain.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm looking toward this direction however my issue is a bit different. What can happen is that people can enter via the main domain then enter to the subdomain but it's not possible to have someone enter via the subdomain and then move to the main domain + the cookie is already set to auto....